# AngularJS routing ui routeur

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, routes

i'm french, sorry for my bad english

I got a problem with ui routing :

Error: Invalid state ref '({ sport: dataSettings.sport, championnat: dataSettings.championnat })equipes'

My app.js

```
betotopApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/football/ligue1/equipes');

   $stateProvider
      .state('equipes', {
         url: '/:sport/:championnat/equipes',
         templateUrl : 'library/views/equipes.html',
         controller  : 'equipesCtrl',
         abstract: true
      })
      .state('calendrier', {
         url: '/:sport/:championnat/calendrier',
         templateUrl : 'library/views/calendrier.html',
         controller  : 'calendrierCtrl',
         abstract: true
      })
      .state('matchs', {
         url: '/:sport/:championnat/matchs',
         templateUrl : 'library/views/matchs.html',
         controller  : 'matchsCtrl',
         abstract: true
      })
      .state('classement', {
         url: '/:sport/:championnat/classement',
         templateUrl : 'library/views/classement.html',
         controller  : 'classementCtrl',
         abstract: true
      })
      .state('statistiques', {
         url: '/:sport/:championnat/statistiques',
         templateUrl : 'library/views/statistiques.html',
         controller  : 'statistiquesCtrl',
         abstract: true
      });
});
```

and my index.html

```
<a ui-sref="({ sport: dataSettings.sport, championnat: dataSettings.championnat })equipes" class="c"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> Equipes</a>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the state wrongly, should be:

```
<a ui-sref="equipes({ sport: dataSettings.sport, championnat: dataSettings.championnat })" class="c"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> Equipes</a>
```

The url is what you put in the browser and is different from the state name.

Reference: [ui-sref](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)

Answer (score -1):

Oh thanks, it works.

But why in my url "equipes" is at the end, and here, i've to put it at the beginning ?

Comment: You should put this as a comment instead of an answer